# Unable to get profile variable using ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, environment-variables

Unable to retrieve the profile variable using ssh.

server2 ==> user apptst ==> bash profile has $APPHOME variable.

Was trying to retrieve the value from server1 using ssh but failed.

Used options below

```
server1> ssh apptst@server2 'echo $APPHOME'

server1> ssh apptst@server2 echo '$APPHOME'

server1> ssh apptst@server2 echo "$APPHOME"

server1> ssh apptst@server2 "echo $APPHOME"
```

when tried

```
server1> ssh apptst@server2 ls -ld $APPHOME
```

it works fine.

Any suggestions what is missing and how can I get the variable from server2?

Comment: In the second case the shell on **server1** expands `$APPHOME`, and not server2. Check e.g. with `cd / && ssh apptst@server2 'echo $PWD'` (you need these quotes `'`, otherwise again shell on server1 will expand), which will return `/` and not `~`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the explanation. But all the cases have failed to provide the output. confused completely what mistake I am doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This command should work:

```
 server1> ssh apptst@server2 'bash -l -c "echo \$APPHOME"'
```

- you need `'` quotes to pass that complete command to ssh as one argument; this also prevents the shell on server1 to expand `$APPHOME` itself
- `bash -l` starts a login shell, which reads in the profiles files, where $APPHOME gets defined (as [@chepner pointed out](https://superuser.com/a/566445/195224) in his answer, this is not default when invoked by sshd)
- `-c` executes the next argument, again with quotes that the complete echo command gets executed.
- escaping `\$` is necessary, because otherwise the *parent (non-login) shell* which sshd invokes (and which inherits the environment diretly from init (*)) does expand `$APPHOME`. But this is too early as `$APPHOME` only gets defined for *login* shells (via `~/.profile`). [*added this point after comment from OP*]

---

(*) correct me, if I'm wrong here.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply...

I tried as suggested but still I am getting a blank output only.

Comment: @user2119462: This becomes really weired, I think I can reproduce your issue now. Try this really ugly workaround: `ssh apptst@server2 'bash -l -c "set | grep ^APPHOME"'`

Comment: @mpy...thanks for the workaround it worked fine. But still could not understand why the first solution is not working

Comment: @user2119462 Did you try the improved answer? I'm really interested if that works now, too!

Comment: @mpy...the Improved answer worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you specify an exact command to run via `ssh`, the remote `sshd` does *not* start a login shell to execute it, but a regular non-interactive shell. In that case, `.bash_profile` is not executed, and so `APPHOME` is not defined.

And while typing this, mph has posted the [correct solution](https://superuser.com/a/566444/126224) to force a login shell that processes `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Thanks Chepner.....but there is no output. I tried to assign it to a variable but still was having the same issue, blank output.