# SSH not reading rc files

Tags: bash, ssh

Once upon a time, an ssh invocation to `host1` like `ssh u@host1 command` would read .bashrc before executing `command`. `host2` is administered by the same people, and reads .bashrc!

I don't administer `host1` or `host2`, but sometime in the last 6 months it seems this behaviour has changed.

It seems now that **no** rc file is being read on login: I edited `.profile, .bash_profile, .bashrc, .login` to append their name to a variable when read (`export READ=$READ:.profile`)

The results surprised me:

```
> ssh u@host1
bash3.2> echo $READ
:.bash_profile:.profile
```

As I expected.

```
> ssh u@host1 echo \$READ

>
```

So now I'm stuck. Any suggestions on how this could be happening? Is this a SSHd settings issue?

And just for info: `host2` is running a version of OpenSSH even older than `host1`, and both are running the same bash version. `host1` runs AIX, `host2` runs linux.

**Edit**: I can't change the `ssh` command line because the goal here is to make `git` work properly, for a couple of non-super-users, where `git` is installed (for other reasons) on a non-standard path. The relation to this question is that because the location of `git-unpack` is specified in `.bashrc`, `git clone` from this remote has stopped working. So the RC problem needs to be fixed, because I'm trying to set this up for non-super-users, and so `git-clone -u` is not really a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Who is host2? You only mention host1 in your question. Are you connecting from a Linux machine?

Comment: @terdon Whoops. Broke my train of thought and left a sentence fragment in there. Edited to add "host2 is administered by the same people, and reads .bashrc!"

Comment: I think file permissions changed when you edited the files. This has happened to me before, but I can't remember the fix =/

Comment: OK, this might be an AIX issue cause I can't replicate it when sshing between two linux boxes.

Comment: When logging in to my user account at the university I have the same problem that .bashrc isn't read and I have to manually source .bashrc. The server is running "OpenSSH_4.3p2 Debian-9etch3, OpenSSL 0.9.8c 05 Sep 2006" uname -a says: "Linux rzstud3 2.6.38.6 #1 SMP Mon May 16 14:26:06 CEST 2011 i686 GNU/Linux"

Comment: @ekaj Well, if you recall, I'd love to hear! Tried 666 and 777 on .bashrc, and still no luck.

Comment: @FSMaxB Do you know if you have *any* rcfiles being read? Or just not .bashrc?

Comment: @Keggert /etc/profile seems to work (I don't have rights to change it but 'env' shows me variables that are specified in /etc/profile only)

Comment: See my answer http://superuser.com/a/566444/195224 for an explanation why you should try `ssh u@host1 'bash -l -c "echo \$READ"'`.

Comment: I would be surprised if `.bashrc` *were* read, since `ssh host1 echo \$READ` doesn't start an interactive shell.

Comment: @chepner It sure is, at least on the linux `host2`, and *was* once upon a time on `host1`.

Comment: @mpy Sure, that works, however doesn't solve the problem that this is the root of. Will edit question to mention this, but the problem is that because the location of git-unpack is specified in .bashrc, git clone from this remote has stopped working. So the RC problem needs to be fixed, because I'm trying to set this up for non-super-users, and so git-clone -u is not really a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @chepner: `.bashrc` is really `source`'d for `ssh host cmd`. See [my comments here](http://serverfault.com/a/485497/66862).

Comment: @chepner: Or look at [the explanation from Chet](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2012-06/msg00028.html).

Comment: @Keggert if `~/.bashrc` is read when doing `ssh`, then it is probably being called by `.profile` or `bash_profile`. It has no business being read otherwise. What is weird is that your `~./profile` is not read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular instance, the answer appears (unfortunately) to be an instance of [buggy software](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=458839) (or a bug very similar to that linked one).

If you control bash on that machine, you may be able to fix it by recompiling bash with `#define SSH_SOURCE_BASHRC`; However it's not the case for me, so I'm stuck seeking other options.

Hopefully that helps someone.

Comment: #define SSH_SOURCE_BASHRC saved my day. THX.

Comment: That may have worked but is not the correct answer. Per default bash reads the .profile,  .bash_profile, .bash_login and .login on loging in from a remote. If you dont want them to be read try this  --> ssh hostname "bash --noprofile"

Comment: `ssh hostname bash --noprofile` isn't a prefect solution.  Before your command is executed the remote host will still execute the user's default shell as a login shell which will still read things like `.login`.  If the user has a particularly wonky/strange setup (eg., a `.login` that sources their `.bashrc`), it can still affect the environment before your command runs.