# SSH remote command no reading all environment variables

Tags: git, bash, ssh

I have declared some "PATH" variables in the ".bashrc" file of a remote machine. When I login to the remote machine, all these "PATH" variables work fine. But when I do a "ssh user@remote env", the "PATH"s declared in the ".bashrc" are not read. How can I fix this?

This is the ".bash_profile" in the home directory on the remote machine:

```
# .bash_profile
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:

export PATH
```

This is the ".bashrc" in the home directory on the remote machine:

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
. /etc/bashrc
fi

# PATH
export PATH=$HOME/git-1.8/bin/:$PATH
```

And this is the present output of the command "ssh user@remote env" from my local machine:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
SSH_CLIENT=NNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
USER=XXXXXXXXX
MAIL=/var/mail/XXXXXXXX
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/openssh/bin
PWD=/volume2/home/hp120242/XXXXXXXXX
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/hp120242/XXXXXXXXXX
LOGNAME=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
SSH_CONNECTION=NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
_=/bin/env
```

I don't have root permissions on the remote.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer: [SSH not reading rc files](https://superuser.com/questions/571837/ssh-not-reading-rc-files)

---

`.bash_profile` is not executed when running a command because SSH does not execute a login shell, it executes the command. You can try setting the environment variables in `~/.ssh/environment` but it's possible that the reading of this file has been disabled.

You could try forcing a login shell via: `ssh user@host bash -lc env`.

As others have mentioned `.bashrc` should be read when running a command. Can you verify that this is the case by adding something like `echo EXECUTED` to the *top* of your `.bashrc`.

It is also possible that whatever is in `/etc/bashrc` is calling `exit` so anything below that is not run.

Comment: Shouldn't .bashrc should still be sourced though?

Comment: I created a ".ssh/environment" file with the following line "export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/git-1.8/bin" at the remote home folder but it didn't change nothing. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes, I don't understand why is not being sourced.

Comment: For `.ssh/environment` to work, you cannot have export on the line, and `PermitUserEnvironment` needs to be set in the `sshd_config`... which @jhaprade has no control over.

Comment: Running "ssh <hostname> env" definitely reads the ~/.bashrc on the Linux I'm using, even with the .ssh/, .profile and other .bash* files hidden.  I seem to remember this leading to some strange circumlocutions in making sure it read in my normal environment variables IFF they were absent.  Note that this still fits the idea of bash not being called as a "login shell", since that would be the .bash_login or .bash_profile or .profile instead.

Answer (score 1):

On my box, stuffing `export HI=THERE` into an otherwise empty `~/.bashrc` shows this output when ssh is used to contact the box for an env listing:

```
$ ssh $host /usr/bin/env 2>/dev/null | grep HI
HI=THERE
```

My `~/.bashrc` takes the approach of checking for a user-specific environment variable and then, if it's missing, does the equivalent of:

```
. ~/.profile   # load in (Bourne-shell syntax) baseline environment variables
```

Hence, my ssh commands - even though bash starts up as though it's a subshell (.bashrc only) - still get the environment variables I normally expect for non-interactive shells.  I t seem to remember doing this explicitly for SSH many years ago.

You could have your `~/.profile` set some variable, say `ENVGOOD=true`, then have this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
[ -z "$ENVGOOD" ] && . ~/.profile  # sets ENVGOOD=true
```

or create a `~/.ssh/environment`.  Note that this latter will only work if `PermitUserEnvironment = true` in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is set, which is *NOT* the default (and assuredly why my setup doesn't rely on it).

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS/RHEL, I've done the following

```
ssh user@host "source .bash_profile; env "
```

Do not forgot to \$ so that you use the remote environment variables. For example,
The following command will print the same value

```
echo $SSH_CLIENT; ssh user@host "source .bash_profile; echo $SSH_CLIENT "
```

The command below

```
echo $SSH_CLIENT; ssh user@host "source .bash_profile; echo \$SSH_CLIENT "
```

will print what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

On the remote machine, verify your sshd process does not have an option that is overriding your PATH.

```
ps aux | grep sshd
```